# No map by facebook custom story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

When i am trying to display a map layout from Facebook Open Graph no map is shown in the post.

The post look like:

[image]

My **layout settings** are:
[image]

and my **object** looks like:

[image]

i am calling the `Open Graph API` with following `meta tags`:

```
  %meta{:property => 'og:type', :content => 'APP_NAMESPACE:OBJECT' }
  %meta{:property => 'fb:app_id', :content => FacebookService.facebook_keys['app_id'] }
  %meta{:property => 'og:title', :content => 'Title' }
  %meta{:property => 'og:image', :content => 'https://b9eeb50d.ngrok.io/assets/itunes.png' }
  %meta{:property => 'og:url', :content => 'https://b9eeb50d.ngrok.io/admin/posts' }

  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:speed', :content => '2'}
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:speed:units', :content => 'm/s'}
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:distance', :content => '3' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:distance:units', :content => 'km' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:duration', :content => '10' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:duration:units', :content => 'min' }

  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:startpoint:latitude', :content => '46.646443' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:startpoint:longitude', :content => '14.286696' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:startpoint:altitude', :content => '300' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:endpoint:latitude', :content => '46.637144' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:endpoint:longitude', :content => '14.294555' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:endpoint:altitude', :content => '300' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:highestpoint:latitude', :content => '46.642315' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:highestpoint:longitude', :content => '14.288530' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:highestpoint:altitude', :content => '350' }

  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:latitude', :content => '46.640278' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:longitude', :content => '14.292015' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:altitude', :content => '300' }

  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:latitude', :content => '46.643560' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:longitude', :content => '14.286588' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:altitude', :content => '310' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:latitude', :content => '48.892712' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:longitude', :content => '9.1751' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:altitude', :content => '310' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:latitude', :content => '48.893503' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:longitude', :content => '9.180593' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:altitude', :content => '310' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:latitude', :content => '48.893503' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:longitude', :content => '9.180593' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:altitude', :content => '310' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:latitude', :content => '48.889552' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:longitude', :content => '9.188318' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:altitude', :content => '310' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:latitude', :content => '48.889552' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:longitude', :content => '9.188318' }
  %meta{:property => 'APP_NAMESPACE:route:altitude', :content => '310' }
```

does anybody has an idea what i am making wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've open a bug on facebook developper to have some help ! may be you can follow it at this link : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/882577895191154/ and can solved your problem too